# AWS SNS: Handling topics that no one subscribed to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am studying SNS to use in my application and got to a problem that i couldnt find any documentation or people talking about on the internet (Closest thing i found to my problem was here, but it isnt even about aws: [MQTT: Subscribe to topics that no client subscribed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401482/mqtt-subscribe-to-topics-that-no-client-subscribed-to))

Here is the thing: I want to use an SNS to send topics to queues, but the application sending the message can send any topic (to which the respective queue will listen to). But what if it is a topic that no one is subscribed to? Can a create a queue that will handle anything that no one else does? Will SQS do that for me automatically? What can i do?

Comment: You are mixing SQS and SNS. *"SNS to send topics to queues"* - you means sending notifications / messages from topics to queues? *"But what if it is a topic that no one is subscribed to?"* - then the message is lost. Can you create a queue that listens to all non-subscribed topics? Not automatically, no. You can try monitoring all topics in your account and react to any subscribe or unsubscribe events happening and then subscribe or unsubscribe your one default queue accordingly but this will probably a pain.

Comment: Why do you want a catch-all? If nobody is subscribed, nobody is interested and the message should be lost.

Comment: I need it because ill be expecting a file creation on S3, i need to let the application who sent the message to know that this will never happen bc no one is subscribed to that topic. Does the "message being lost" trigger some event or something that i can do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no feature in Amazon SNS to handle situations where there are 'no subscribers' on a queue. You would need to handle such logic yourself.

Comment: thank you then! ill see what i can do